# How to stack multiple columns together and put them side by side?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

My data set looks like this

```
structure(list(treatment = c("T5", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T5", "T5", 
"T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T4", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T5", "T4", "T3", "T2", "T1", "T5", "T4", "T3", "T2", 
"T1", "T5", "T4", "T3", "T2", "T1", "T5", "T4", "T3", "T2", "T1", 
"T5", "T4", "T3", "T2", "T1"), block = c("B3", "B2", "B1", "B3", 
"B2", "B1", "B3", "B2", "B1", "B3", "B2", "B1", "B3", "B2", "B1", 
"B3", "B2", "B1", "B3", "B2", "B1", "B3", "B2", "B1", "B3", "B2", 
"B1", "B3", "B2", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B1"), position = c("B", 
"B", "B", "F", "F", "F", "B", "B", "B", "F", "F", "F", "B", "B", 
"B", "F", "F", "F", "B", "B", "B", "F", "F", "F", "B", "B", "B", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F"), year = c(2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022), leaf_quality = c(5, 6, 7, 5, 7, 6, 7, 
6, 6, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5, 8, 9, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 4, 6, 8, 8, 6, 6, 3, 4, 7, 5, 8, 7, 8, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 
7, 7, 5, 6, 6, 8), `1branching` = c(5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 
4, 3, 3, 3, 3), `2branching` = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
3, 4, 4, 3), `3branching` = c(3, 5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 
4, 2, 4), `4branching` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 5, 
4, 5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3), `5branching` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 
3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3), `1height` = c(17, 
21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 22, 18, 25, 22, 20, 19, 20, NA, 19, 20, 
21, 19, 16, 18, 17, 18, 17, 18, 18, 19, 17, 17, 16, 21, 19, 23, 
22, 25, 23, 22, 20, 22, 22, 19, 20, 19, 23, 20, 23, 25, 26, 22, 
25, 26, 23, 24, 24, 26), `2height` = c(20, 21, 21, 22, 21, 23, 
20, 23, 17, 23, 20, 19, 18, 19, 21, 19, 21, 20, 19, 17, 19, 19, 
18, 17, 19, NA, 19, 18, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 21, 19, 19, 17, 19, 
21, 18, 22, 23, 22, 18, 23, 24, 24, 23, 23, 21, 27, 26, 24, 26, 
24), `3height` = c(18, 18, 17, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 23, 22, 20, 
21, 19, 16, 20, 17, 18, 19, 20, 17, 19, 19, 18, 18, 17, NA, NA, 
18, 18, 16, 22, 22, 22, 20, 19, 21, 24, 20, 22, 23, 21, 24, 20, 
18, 23, 23, 19, 27, 25, 23, 26, 27, 24, 26, 27), `4height` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 19, 25, 22, 
23, 20, 23, 21, 21, 21, 21, 20, 21, 19, 19, 19, 24, 25, 25, 24, 
24, 23, 27, 23, 27, 25), `5height` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 22, 23, 23, 23, 21, 21, 22, 22, 
22, 18, 21, 20, 20, 19, 23, 23, 25, 25, 22, 25, 26, 25, 26, 28, 
23), `1_rooting` = c(9, 8, 7, 8, 8, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 
NA, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
), `2_rooting` = c(8, 8, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 7, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, NA, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 3, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
), `3_rooting` = c(9, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, NA, NA, 9, 9, 9, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 6, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
), `4_rooting` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 7, 7, 7, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 8, 
8, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), `5_rooting` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 7, 8, 8, 
8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8), `1_weight` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24, 24, 28, 31, 26, 26, 29, 27, 24, 
28, 31, 22, 24, 26, 27), `2_weight` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 30, 31, 21, 21, 22, 31, 32, 17, 25, 24, 23, 22, 32, 34, 
31), `3_weight` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 27, 29, 23, 
22, 29, 38, 16, 25, 32, 27, 23, 23, 28, 27, 26), `4_weight` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 32, 20, 22, 26, 22, 30, 31, 28, 30, 
28, 22, 33, 26, 32, 20), `5_weight` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 32, 26, 19, 20, 32, 25, 30, 34, 23, 30, 35, 28, 25, 38, 
25)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-55L))
```

I have some columns 1_rooting, 2_rooting,3_rooting etc. I need to stack all the rooting column, branching column, height column and weight column separately and put them side by side.The final result should look something like this

[image]

I am using the following code, but it's only taking 1 set of traits at a time. I need all 4 traits (rooting, branching, height and weight) together in one excel file side by side.

```
branchingdata<-gather(trial,"pot_number","branching",6:10)
```

Any help? Thank you

I tried merging, pivot longer but so far no luck

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what you want exactly. It's unclear to me in your expected output, how you get 1-8 in the "rooting" and "branching" columns. I'm only seeing values of 6:9 in the rooting_x columns of your sample dt.

If you're trying to melt all of the trait columns AND keep the values associated with each column, an option for that can be found below.

You can use `data.table::melt` to transform from wide-to-long on a subset of columns. First, I'll create a list to define the variable and value cols and the pattern to select each trait group to melt. I pass in each argument into melt, subset to the new melted columns and `cbind` the result.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(dta) # your sample data

melt_names = list(
  list(val = "rooting", var = "rooting_trait", pat = "^\\d_r"),
  list(val = "branching", var = "branching_trait", pat = "^\\db"),
  list(val = "height", var = "height_trait", pat = "^\\dh"),
  list(val = "weight", var = "weight_trait", pat = "^\\d_w")
)

# use do.call to cbind each list into a data.table
traits = do.call(cbind, lapply(melt_names, function(nms) {
  # melt only the columns in each trait group
  melt_d = melt(dta, measure.vars = patterns(nms$pat), variable.name = nms$var, value.name = nms$val)
  long_cols = c(nms$var, nms$val)
  # return the columns of interest
  return(melt_d[,..long_cols])
})

head(traits, 10)
```

```
   rooting_trait rooting branching_trait branching height_trait height weight_trait weight
 1:     1_rooting       9      1branching         5      1height     17     1_weight     NA
 2:     1_rooting       8      1branching         5      1height     21     1_weight     NA
 3:     1_rooting       7      1branching         5      1height     21     1_weight     NA
 4:     1_rooting       8      1branching         3      1height     20     1_weight     NA
 5:     1_rooting       8      1branching         5      1height     20     1_weight     NA
 6:     1_rooting       7      1branching         5      1height     20     1_weight     NA
 7:     1_rooting       8      1branching         5      1height     20     1_weight     NA
 8:     1_rooting       9      1branching         4      1height     22     1_weight     NA
 9:     1_rooting       8      1branching         5      1height     18     1_weight     NA
10:     1_rooting       9      1branching         5      1height     25     1_weight     NA
```